# Kernel ridge regression in python for multiple features

Tags: python, kernel, regression

I am creating a statistical model for a set of samples which has 8 features. I am trying KRR (Kernel Ridge Regression) method for the moment to fit the data. I was able to fit the KRR model for 1 feature and all the samples now I am trying to fit the model for 2, 3, 4, ...8 features. Does anyone know how to create a generalized KRR model to fit the multiple features? Thanks

Comment: Did you find how to do this?.